# Bash (or alternative) to find and replace a number of patterns in csv file using another csv file

Tags: string, bash, csv, awk

I have a very large csv file that is too big to open in excel for this operation.

I need to replace a specific string for approx 6000 records out of the 1.5mil in the csv, the string itself is in the comma separated format like so:

```
ABC,FOO.BAR,123456
```

With other columns on either side that are of no concern. I only need enough to get enough data to make sure the final data string (the numbers) are unique.

I have another file with the string to replace and the replacement string like (for the above):

```
"ABC,FOO.BAR,123456","ABC,FOO.BAR,654321"
```

So in the case above 123456 is being replaced by 654321. A simple (yet maddeningly slow) way to do this is open both docs in notepad++ and find the first string then replace with the second string, but with over 6000 records this isnt great.

I was hoping someone could give advice on a scripting solution? e.g.:

```
$file1 = base.csv
$file2 = replace.csv

For each row in $file2 {
awk '{sub(/$file2($firstcolumn)/,$file2($Secondcolumn)' $file1 
}
```

Though Im not entirely sure how to adapt awk to do an operation like this..

EDIT: Sorry I should have been more specific, the data in my replacement csv is only in two columns; two raw strings!

Comment: The remaining question: does  `ABC,FOO.BAR,123456` in your _data_ file (`base.csv`) represent _3_ fields or is it the contents of a _single_ field that is enclosed in `"..."` _in the file_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it would be easier of course if your delimiter is not used within the fields...

you can do in two steps, create a `sed` script from the lookup file and use it for the main data file for replacements

for example,
(assumes there is no escaped quotes in the fields, may not hold)

```
$ awk -F'","' '{print "s/" $1 "\"/\"" $2 "/"}' lookup_file > replace.sed
$ sed -f replace.sed data_file
```

Comment: It's an elegant solution, but comes with a caveat: To make this fully robust, you'd have to escape metacharacters in both the search and replacement strings (in the sample input, only `.` is a concern) - `sed` offers no _literal_ string substitution.

Comment: fields should be quoted in the data file, otherwise the fields with commas will break the integrity. You're right about escaping all meta chars in `sed` but not sure needed for this file.  Another problem area is if there are escaped quotes in the fields as well.

Comment: Or avoid the tmp file with `sed -f <(awk -F'","' '{print "s/" $1 "\"/\"" $2 "/"}' lookup_file) data_file`.

Comment: I went for this solution in the end as I hadnt used sed so was good to learn something new. Took a very long time to run due to the sample size but worked like a charm, cheers

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F\" '
 NR==FNR { subst[$2]=$4; next }
 { 
   for (s in subst) {
     pos = index($0, s)
     if (pos) {
       $0 = substr($0, 1, pos-1) subst[s] substr($0, pos + length(s))
       break
     }
   }
   print
 }
' "$file2" "$file1"  # > "$file1.$$.tmp" && mv "$file1.$$.tmp" "$file1"
```

<sup>The part after the `#` shows how you could replace the input data file with the output.</sup>

- The block associated with `NR==FNR` is only executed for the first input file, the one with the search and replacement strings.

  - `subst[$2]=$4` builds an associative array (dictionary): the key is the search string, the value the replacement string.
  - Fields `$2` and `$4` are the search string and the replacement string, respectively, because Awk was instructed to break in the input into fields by `"` (`-F\"`); note that this assumes that your strings do not contain escaped *embedded* `"` chars.
- The remaining block then processes the data file:

  - For each input line, it loops over the search strings and looks for a match on the current line:

    - Once a match is found, the replacement string is substituted for the search string, and matching stops.
  - `print` simply prints the (possibly modified) line.

Note that since you want *literal* string replacements, *regex*-based functions such as `sub()` are explicitly avoided in favor of literal string-processing functions `index()` and `substr()`.

As an aside: since you say there are columns on either side in the data file, consider making the search/replacement strings more robust by placing `,` on either side of them (this could be done inside the `awk` script).

Comment: I went for the sed solution in the end but thanks for your solution, and thanks even more for the great explanation of the different pieces of it!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a language with a CSV parsing library rather than trying to do this with shell tools. For example, Ruby:

```
require 'csv'
replacements = CSV.open('replace.csv','r').to_h
File.open('base.csv', 'r').each_line do |line|
  replacements.each do |old, new|
    line.gsub!(old) { new }
  end
  puts line
end
```

Note that [`Enumerable#to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_h) requires Ruby v2.1+; replace with this for older Rubys:

```
replacements = Hash[*CSV.open('replace.csv','r').to_a.flatten]
```

You only really need CSV for the replacements file; this assumes you can apply the substitutions to the other file as plain text, which speeds things up a bit and avoids having to parse the old/new strings out into fields themselves.